# ARCore randomly instantiate prefab on existing planes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

The ARCore demo shows us how to place a prefab on a plane via touch raycasting, but I would like to spawn a prefab randomly around the room via C# script once we have a certain amount of floor space scanned.

How would I do this?

Comment: It's possible, yes.

Comment: :|  point taken.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? Would really appreciate it if you could share the answer